# Table 'xxx.__MigrationHistory' doesn't exist error when running update-Database in Entity Framework for MySql database

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

Currently I have an application which uses Entity Framework 6.1.3 along with Sql Server 2012. I use Code first migration approach for my DB. In Sql Server DB, I have created tables with schema name as table prefix, such as TestDB.TestSchema.tblXyz where TestDB is my database and TestSchema is my schema name.

Now I want to change my application to use MySql database and to follow the same convention for table name and schema.

I overrided the onModelCreating method of HistoryContext class to add a prefix to tables as following ,

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("TestSchema");
        modelBuilder.Entity<HistoryRow>().Property(h => h.MigrationId).HasMaxLength(128).IsRequired();
        modelBuilder.Entity<HistoryRow>().Property(h => h.ContextKey).HasMaxLength(200).IsRequired();
    }
```

But when I ran update-database -verbose command in the package manager console, it gave the error 
"Table '**TestDB.__MigrationHistory**' doesn't exist".

Below is the a part of the script generated while running migration :

```
create table `TestSchema.__MigrationHistory` (`MigrationId` varchar(128)  
not null    ,`ContextKey` varchar(200)  not null ,`Model` longblob 
not null,`ProductVersion` varchar(32)  not null ,primary key (
`MigrationId`,`ContextKey`) ) engine=InnoDb auto_increment=0
INSERT INTO `__MigrationHistory`( ...
```

As you can see while inserting into __MigrationHistory table, it is not prefixing the schema name to that. So it is resulting in the above error.

Do anybody else have faced the same issue? What can be done here to make Entity Framework pick the right table name?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You must to remove this row:

```
modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("TestSchema");
```

Then EF stops to add schema prefix to each table name.
Tables will be created in tablespace specified in connection string (parameter "Initial Catalog=..." is app.config).